# How Session Token works in .net applications

Tags: wif, identity, claims-based-identity, federated-identity

I am working with .Net application where my requirement is to work with session token. How can I generate session token and use that token to allow the user to access the certain resources of my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you mean the WIF Session Authentication Module (SAM) from .NET 4.5 for session tokens? Here's something to get you started:

http://brockallen.com/2013/01/26/replacing-forms-authentication-with-wifs-session-authentication-module-sam-to-enable-claims-aware-identity/